# Mail merge with richtext fields

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

If I have a RichText editor in my Dynamics CRM 2011, and saves the data it will be saved with HTML markup.
How do I use these fields in a mail merge scenario?
If I add the field to Word, the markup is just showing up, but not the formatting!

Are there any codes that can be set in the field codes?

or?

Any solution is greatly appreciated :)

/Christian

Comment: What are you using as a Rich Text editor? There's nothing out-of-box to provide that functionality in Dynamics CRM 2011.

Comment: using ADX Studio Community pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this.

using Documents Core Pack will solve these issues, it has just implemented HTML functionality